# buttonLabel option of electron dialog seems not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

According to the documentation (https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md) , I should be able to change the text on the confirmation button using `buttonLabel` option. However,

```
const {dialog} = require('electron').remote;
//...
dialog.showOpenDialog({
  title: '',
  buttonLabel: 'Save',
  properties: ['openDirectory', 'createDirectory']
}, (result) => {
  //...
})
```

The confirmation button is still shown as '**Open**' instead of '**Save**'

I'm in macOS 10.12.4.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of electron are you using?

Comment: Works here. OSX 10.11.6 Electron 1.6.6

Comment: I'm using `"electron-prebuilt": "^0.35.0"`